# FluentValidation client side validation not working for inherited class

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Client side validation is working for 'CompanyName' fine but for inherited class i.e shipping & billing its not working. Please suggest the solution.

```
[Validator(typeof(ClientValidator))]
public class Client
{
    public string CompanyName{get;set;}

    private volatile Contact Shipping = null;
    private volatile Contact Billing = null;

}

public class Contact : Address
{

}

public class Address
{

public String Name{get;set;}

    public String Phone{get;set;}
}


public class ClientValidator : AbstractValidator<Client>

{

        public ClientValidator()

{

RuleFor(x => x.CompanyName).NotNull().WithMessage("Required").Length(1, 15).WithMessage("Length issue.");


            RuleFor(x => x.Shipping.Name).NotNull().WithMessage("Required").Length(1, 15).WithMessage("Length issue.");

            RuleFor(x => x.Shipping.Phone).NotNull().WithMessage("Required").Length(1, 15).WithMessage("Length issue.");
            RuleFor(x => x.Billing.Name).NotNull().WithMessage("Required").Length(1, 15).WithMessage("Length issue.");
            RuleFor(x => x.Billing.Phone).NotNull().WithMessage("Required").Length(1, 15).WithMessage("Length issue.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For containment object fluentvalidation doesn't work as you have implemented.

For this refer complex properties validation from fluent validation and try with below code.

```
[Validator(typeof(ClientValidator))]
public class Client
{
    public string CompanyName{get;set;}
    private volatile Contact Shipping = null;
    private volatile Contact Billing = null;
}

public class Contact : Address
{

}

public class Address
{
    public String Name{get;set;}
    public String Phone{get;set;}
}

public class AddressValidator : AbstractValidator<Address>
{
    public ClientValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().WithMessage("Required").Length(1, 15).WithMessage("Length issue.");
        RuleFor(x => x.Phone).NotNull().WithMessage("Required").Length(1, 15).WithMessage("Length issue.");
    }
} 

public class ClientValidator : AbstractValidator<Client>
{
    public ClientValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.CompanyName).NotNull().WithMessage("Required").Length(1, 15).WithMessage("Length issue.");
        RuleFor(x => x.Shipping).SetValidator(new AddressValidator());
        RuleFor(x => x.Billing).SetValidator(new AddressValidator());
    }
}
```